# Testing for significance without microdata?

Tags: statistical-significance, survey

I have a bunch of output from a survey but don't have access to the microdata. What I have are counts, proportions, and standard errors from variables that I specify. Is there a way to properly determine if 2 proportions are significantly different? For example 60% of men are employed and 45% of women. Right now I'm saying that if the CI don't overlap they are different and calling it a "conservative method", but I have a lot of cases where things are coming out as not significant and I would like to be more precise if possible.

Edit: From what I've found I can't do this because to perform an unpaired t-test I would also need the sample sizes which I don't have, I have the weighted counts.

Comment: Do you have standard error for the proportions to form test statistics? What do you mean "standard errors from variables"? Standard errors only happen to estimators not variables.